# Laravel mailgun driver ignores verified domain and uses sandbox instead

Tags: laravel-5, mailgun

I'm trying to use mailgun to send notifications to users. I have verified domain, but even though my `config\services.php` file looks like this:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => 'mg.mydomain.biz',
    'secret' => 'key-3223423423n423j42jklkj23l',
],
```

all the emails go through sandbox domain.

`php artisan config:clear` does not help. It is the same with development and production environment. Also I need to point out that emails come from `@maydomain.biz` when `config\mail.php` clearly states `'from' => ['address' => 'no-reply@mg.mydomain.biz', 'name' => 'Sender'],`. I channged it hours ago and cleared config cache un restarted web server since.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo service supervisor restart` solved the problem.

Comment: @PetterFriberg it is, but i can accept my own answer tomorrow